# Orbeon : having checkboxes inside control's settings

Tags: orbeon, xbl

I'm writing my custom control (XBL) and wondering : it possible to have checkboxes inside control's Basic Settings in Form Builder, not only xf:input fields ?

I would appreciate any examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently support for `xf:input` is hardcoded. You can see how this is implemented [here](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/4ec537dc599fe637b9562e10592e398118cc55d9/src/resources-packaged/xbl/fb/dialog-control-details/dialog-control-details.xbl#L323) .

It wouldn't be too hard to add support for other controls. Another idea would be to use `xxf:dynamic`, in effect creating a little subform, so that we don't have to interpret the XForms by hand.

Comment: Thank you very much - it was easy-peasy !